# What is the most efficient way to find and replace continuing duplicates in the string?

Tags: python

What is the most efficient way to find and replace continuing duplicates in the string? I'm trying to make a script that finds continuing duplicates in the string and replaces them.

For example, after removing repeated substring of length 1: “abcababceccced” --> “abcababceced” (2 'c' are removed)
After removing repeated substring of length 2: “abcababceced” --> “abcabceced” (substring “ab” is removed)
and so on...

This is how I tried so far, but it seems not working properly as I wanted...

```
def f(a, b):
    l = a
    for j in range(len(a)):
        try:
            if l[j:j+b] == l[j+b:j+2*b]:
                l = l[:j+b] + l[j+2*b:]
            else: continue
        except:
            break
    return l, b+1

x = "string"
b = 1
while True:
    if b <= int(len(x)/2):
        x, b = f(x,b)
    else: break
print(x)
```

Comment: Define "not working properly". The first step to being able to fix any problem is being able to _identify_ and _describe_ the problem. Do you go to a doctor and say "I don't feel well?" or do you give more specific details? See [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: This only works for length 1, but it could be an interesting place to start: `''.join([x for i, x in enumerate(t_str) if t_str[i+1-len(t_str)] != x])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to the question. It tries to minimize string slicing (which can be inefficient since it copies the sliced substring) in the search for duplicates by using the `find()` method of the built-in `str` data type.

```py
x = "abcababceccced"
print(x)
patLen = 1
while patLen * 2 < len(x):
    i = 0
    while i + patLen * 2 < len(x):
        jPrev, j, pat = i, i + patLen, x[i:i + patLen]
        while j + patLen <= len(x) and x.find(pat, j) == j:
            jPrev, j = j, j + patLen
        if j > i + patLen:
            print(f"{' '*i + x[i:j - patLen]} removed")
            x = x[:i] + x[j - patLen:]
            print(x)
        i += 1
    patLen += 1
```

Output:

```
abcababceccced
         cc removed
abcababceced
   ab removed
abcabceced
     ce removed
abcabced
abc removed
abced
```

Note that your original code can also be made to work with the following modifications (I added a couple of print statements too, to show what it's doing):

```py
def f(a, b):
    l = a
    for j in range(len(a) - 2 * b):
        try:
            while l[j:j+b] == l[j+b:j+2*b]:
                print(f"{' '*(j+b) + l[j+b:j+2*b]} removed")
                l = l[:j+b] + l[j+2*b:]
            else: continue
        except:
            break
    return l, b+1

x = "abcababceccced"
b = 1
while b <= int(len(x) // 2):
    print(x)
    x, b = f(x,b)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
abcababceccced
          c removed
          c removed
abcababceced
     ab removed
       ce removed
abcabced
   abc removed
abced
```